# jQuery getJSON syntax error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery's `$.getJSON()` function to make a server-side AJAX call:

```
$.getJSON() {
    url: "/my-server/some-url",
    success: function() {
        alert("Success!");
    }
}
```

Firebug shows this as a JavaScript error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]   

$.getJSON() {
```

In reading the [tutorial](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) it appears that I'm using it right, passing in a URL and then a success callback. This particular URL doesn't require any data parameters, so I omitted them. Can anyone spot where I'm going awrye? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to call a function, using the [getJSON arguments](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$.getJSON("/my-server/some-url", function(data) {
        alert("Success!");
});
```

Or use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) passing an object:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/my-server/some-url",
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data) {
            alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

To pass data (e.g. `{ dog: 1, cat: 4 }` which will be converted to URL parameters) you can pass the object directly to both functions:

```
$.getJSON("/my-server/some-url", { dog : 1, cat : 4 }, function(data) {
        alert("Success!");
});
// Or
$.ajax({
    url : "/my-server/some-url",
    dataType : 'json',
    data : { dog : 1, cat : 4 },
    success : function(data) {
            alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

Comment: I was using a wrong signature first using $.getJSON instead of $.ajax.

Comment: @user1689607 Because the answer was wrong before it was corrected through edits.

Comment: Thanks @Daff - please see my question under Aktee's answer - I have the same question for you!

Comment: I elaborated a little more with an example how to pass data.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong. Try this:

```
$.getJSON("/my-server/some-url",function() {
         alert("Success!");
     }
});
```

Your code is closer to the `$.ajax` method.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/my-server/some-url",
    success: function() {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

You can also pass URL arguments with the `data` parameter.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

> Data that is sent to the server is appended to the URL as a query
>   string. If the value of the data parameter is an object (map), it is
>   converted to a string and url-encoded before it is appended to the
>   URL.

```
$.getJSON("/my-server/some-url",{ dog: 1, cat: 4 },function() {
         alert("Success!");
     }
});

// Requests: "/my-server/some-url?dog=1&cat=4
```

Comment: Thanks @jimp - please see my question under Aktee's answer - I have the same question for you!

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct syntax. $.getJSON is a function with parameters. The first parameter is mandatory, and it's a string containing the url.

```
$.getJSON(
    "/my-server/some-url", 
    data,
    function(callback) { 
        alert('success')
    }
);
```

$.getJSON is a shortcut for $.ajax, which is similar to what you wrote. $.ajax takes a single object as a parameter..

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Thanks @Aktee (+1) - question - how do I set data parameters with `$.getJSON`? Let's say I want to use it with a new URL that expects both a `dog` and a `cat` data parameter. Where you right `data` could I just use `{ dog: 1, cat: 4 }` or is there some other trick? Thanks again!

Comment: @pnongrata, It is exactly how you did it! $.getJSON("/url/here", {dog: 1, cat: 1}, callback)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.getJson('url', function(data) {
   //do stuff with data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function is a shorthand for the [`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function

> jQuery.getJSON( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )

```
$.getJSON("/my-server/some-url", function() {
  //Success
  alert("success");
});
```